# Dart - How to start my Tic Tac Toe game in a certain difficulty scale (EASY)

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a tic tac toe game in flutter/dart. I set 3 different difficulties EASY,MEDIUM,HARD. When the user starts the tic tac toe game I want it to start with the EASY difficulty setting right away without having to select easy. How would I do that? The code below is my logic for the different difficulties and the simple dialogue box to set difficulties with. But how do I start the game up in EASY mode as the default?

````
    displayMessage(computerPlayer + " MOVED, X's TURN");

    if (_gameChoice == 1) {
      getRandomMove();
    }
    if (_gameChoice == 2) {
      if (winningCheck == 0) {
        getWinningMove();
      }
      if (winningCheck == 0) {
        getRandomMove();
      }
    }
    if (_gameChoice == 3) {
      if (winningCheck == 0) {
        getWinningMove();
      }
      if (winningCheck == 0 && blockingCheck == 0) {
        getBlockingMove();
      }
      if (winningCheck == 0 && blockingCheck == 0) {
        getRandomMove();
      }
    }
  }

  // Get winning move
  void getWinningMove() {
    // First see if there's a move O can make to win
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
      if (_mBoard[i] != humanPlayer && _mBoard[i] != computerPlayer) {
        String curr = _mBoard[i];
        _mBoard[i] = computerPlayer;
        print(computerPlayer + " made a winning move to " + "$i");
        if (checkWinner() == 3) {
          winningCheck = 1;
          return;
        } else
          _mBoard[i] = curr;
        winningCheck = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get Blocking move
  void getBlockingMove() {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
      if (_mBoard[i] != humanPlayer && _mBoard[i] != computerPlayer) {
        String curr = _mBoard[i]; // Save the current number
        _mBoard[i] = humanPlayer;
        if (checkWinner() == 2) {
          _mBoard[i] = computerPlayer;
          blockingCheck = 1;
          print(computerPlayer + " made a blocking move to" + ' $i');
          return;
        } else
          _mBoard[i] = curr;
        blockingCheck = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get random move
  void getRandomMove() {
    var move;
    // Generate random move
    var count = 0;
    do {
      count = count + 1;
      move = rnd.nextInt(9);
      print("Computer random move is " + '$move');
    } while (
        (_mBoard[move] == humanPlayer || _mBoard[move] == computerPlayer) &&
            (count < 9));

    if ((_mBoard[move] == humanPlayer) || (_mBoard[move] == computerPlayer)) {
      return;
    } else {
      print("Computer is making a move to " + '$move');

      _mBoard[move] = computerPlayer;
      return;
    }
  }

Future _showSimpleDialogue() async {
    switch (await showDialog(
      context: context,
      /*it shows a popup with few options which you can select, for option we
        created enums which we can use with switch statement, in this first switch
        will wait for the user to select the option which it can use with switch cases*/
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('Select the Difficulty Level'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text('Easy'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Choice.EASY);
                computerTurn();
              },
            ),
            new SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text('Medium'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Choice.MEDIUM);
                computerTurn();
              },
            ),
            new SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text('Hard'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Choice.HARD);
                computerTurn();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    )) {
      case Choice.EASY:
        _gameChoice = 1;
        break;
      case Choice.MEDIUM:
        _gameChoice = 2;
        break;
      case Choice.HARD:
        _gameChoice = 3;
        break;
    }

    print('The selection was Choice = ' + '$_gameChoice');
  }```
````

Comment: Made my own tic tac toe in Flutter, perfectly working. Watch this tutorial I made, the code for the game is on github, link in the description. Video -
https://youtu.be/Md9kg8HANMQ

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use a StatefulWidget. Its state object will initialize _gameChoice to Choice.EASY and its value could be updated later, if the user selects another level of difficulty.

```
class TicTacToe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicTacToeState createState() => _TicTacToeState();
}

class _TicTacToeState extends State<TicTacToe> {
  var difficulty = Choice.EASY;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```